# time difference Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, sql, time, difference

I am trying to measure time difference
I am also learning to wright PHP..

I am saving time and date into SQL as datetime by:

```
 $now = new DateTime();
 $datenow = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Logg ( logdate , Log  , value) VALUES ( '$datenow' , 'Log', '$value' )";
```

I can now do a query and get:

```
 $result = mysqli_query( $conn , $sqlq );
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$myLogdate = $row['logdate'];
```

What I am after, is to be able to check the time between

```
$myLogdate
```

and

```
$now = new DateTime();
$datenow = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I have tried:

```
$interval = $datenow->diff($myLogdate);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
echo $elapsed;
```

But I get no results....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Example from the linked page:

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

A list of possible formats can be [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: It seems to stop when I use your and the other example. if I add an echo "test"; in the line after, it will not bee shown on the web page.

Comment: @Bergum: If it just stops, there is an error somewhere else. You have to check your PHP error logs to see if there is a warning or an error.

Comment: Found One:  PHP Warning:  date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in

Comment: Found the error, now how to fix it. What I get from $myLogdate = $row['logdate']; is in the wrong format. How can i fix it?

Comment: @Bergum: `$myLogdate` seems to be a string, as suggested to by the error message, so you need to convert it to `DateTime`: `$datetime = new DateTime($myLogDate);`

Comment: YES! Thank you. That was the answer. Now I have the solution to many problems.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

for finding the date difference try the below code:

```
$interval = date_diff($datenow, $myLogdate);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days')
```

and for format the interval (like "%R%a" means +days) follow http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php.

Comment: No. it's something else.
Can it be an error with $myLogdate and $datenow not being the same type of text/string/whatever?

Comment: Yupp $myLogdate = $row['logdate']; gives me the wrong format. Any tips on how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by waka was:

```
$then = new DateTime($myLogDate);
$interval = date_diff($now, $then);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```